# At which point in the lifecycle should I modify my props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that receives some props. These props need to be mapped to a different structure in order to be usable (for a select, which expects a different structure than our store). I'm wondering at which point in the lifecycle I should do this.

I've read the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html, and it recommends to keep the render function pure:

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify
>   component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked,
>   and it does not read from or write to the DOM or otherwise interact
>   with the browser

Now I'm assuming that it's still ok to map the `props`, as that's not `state` and I'm not changing them:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class IndicatorSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const options = this.props.store.items.map(item => ({ value: item.id, label: item.name }));

    return (
      <div>Display the data in some way here: {options.value} {options.label}</div>
    );
  }
}

ThisComponent.propTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Is this the recommended way, or should the parent component be responsible for formatting the props passed to this component? Or I should I do this in a lifecycle method, or a completely different manner?

Comment: I don't think normalizing the props inside render is a bad idea. Just make sure that you're not mutating the props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, @selvagsz comment is right - normalising `props` inside `render` is not that bad unless you do it heavily. If it's "too much", I would create a container component that normalises the `props` and passes them to a presentational one that only takes care of rendering.

It is not easy to answer the question, but a rule of thumb I follow is:

**A presentational component should receive its props in the most convenient / normalised way possible so that it only takes care of rendering.**

However, for normalisation as in your example it doesn't make sense to create additional container component - the overhead is too big at this point. **When you start feeling the pain of converting props, create a container component and let it convert them for you** or do it in the parent if it's already a container.

Comment: Ah ok. So it's not so black and white, but more tied to scale. If it gets to cumbersome abstract it.

Comment: exactly, you will get a feeling for that with time, don't worry.